# How to find the diameter of a circle in python, using turtle graphics

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to calculate the coordinates for the dots inside the circle. Right now my program is supposed to calculate the dots inside the circle within the square and divide that by the total amount of dots.

```
import turtle
import random


t=turtle.Turtle()
insideCircleCount = 0



def square():
   for y in range(4):
      t.forward(200)
      t.left(90)


def circle():
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(100,0)
    t.pendown()
    t.circle(100)


def randomDot():
    z=int(input("iterations:"))
    for y in range(z):
        t.penup()
        t.pensize(1)
        x=random.randint(0,200)
        y=random.randint(0,200)
        t.goto(x,y)
        t.pendown()
        t.dot()
        insideCircle(x,y)


def insideCircle(x,y):
    if ((x*x + y*y)<100):
        insideCircleCount+=1



#main
square()
circle()
randomDot()
print('Dots inside circle account for ', insideCircleCount)
```

Comment: You need to calculate the distance between the x,y you put into `insideCircle` and the center of your circle. If its less then 100 youre inside else out. Smells like homework to be solved yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle
import random

t=turtle.Turtle()
insideCircleCount = 0

def square():
    for y in range(4):
        t.forward(200)
        t.left(90)

def circle():
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(100,0)
    t.pendown()
    t.circle(100)

def randomDot():
    z=int(input("iterations:"))
    for y in range(z):
        t.penup()
        t.pensize(1)
        x=random.randint(0,200)
        y=random.randint(0,200)
        t.goto(x,y)
        t.pendown()
        t.dot()
        insideCircle(x,y)

def insideCircle(x,y):
    # Here the circle has a offset with center at (100,100)
    #(x – h)^2 + (y – k)^2 = r2
    if (((x-100)**2 + (y-100)**2) < 100**2):
        # you were trying to access a local variable before assignment
        #this fixes that
        global insideCircleCount
        insideCircleCount+=1

#main
square()
circle()
randomDot()
print('Dots inside circle account for ', insideCircleCount)
turtle.mainloop() #stops the window from closing
```